# Accessing Sqlite Database from Sd Card

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sd-card

I have stored my database on the SD card and now I'm trying to access it but it gives me an error :

```
 03-02 15:36:09.653: E/AndroidRuntime(27299): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     03-02 15:36:09.653: E/AndroidRuntime(27299): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start   activity ComponentInfo{com.drturing/com.drturing.ProfileList}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: FeverQuestionTable: , while compiling: Select * from FeverQuestionTable
03-02 15:36:09.653: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
03-02 15:36:09.653: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
03-02 15:36:09.653: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
03-02 15:36:09.653: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
03-02 15:36:09.653: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-02 15:36:09.653: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-02 15:36:09.653: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
03-02 15:36:09.653: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 15:36:09.653: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-02 15:36:09.653: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-02 15:36:09.653: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-02 15:36:09.653: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-02 15:36:09.653: E/AndroidRuntime(27299): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: FeverQuestionTable: , while compiling: Select * from FeverQuestionTable
03-02 15:36:09.653: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
03-02 15:36:09.653: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
03-02 15:36:09.653: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
03-02 15:36:09.653: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
03-02 15:36:09.653: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:127)
03-02 15:36:09.653: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:94)
03-02 15:36:09.653: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:53)
03-02 15:36:09.653: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
03-02 15:36:09.653: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1564)
03-02 15:36:09.653: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1538)
03-02 15:36:09.653: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at com.databasehelper.Developer.getQuestion(Developer.java:62)
```

Comment: -1 for not noticing that the cause of the error is **right there in the log output**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to perform the query `Select * from FeverQuestionTable` in that database but the SQLite database doe not contain a table named `FeverQuestionTable`.

If it is a new SQLite database you have to create that table first by executing `CREATE TABLE FeverQuestionTable ...` followed by the columns you want to create.

See [SQLite documentation CREATE TABLE](http://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) for details.